# Yii:: Could I get the value of the view in the controller

Tags: yii

I create a form use the CActiveForm to create a form.

```
<?php $form = $this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
    'id'=>'report-form',
    'enableAjaxValidation'=>false,
    'enableClientValidation'=>true,
    'focus'=>array($exps[0],'productname'),
)); ?>
```

and when I call the ajax handler in the controller.I want to create a new html string to update the form.

but I can't find the way to get access to value $form!

could I get the value in the controller form the view?

any suggestion would be appreciated!

Comment: in the ajax action(handler) in your controller, you can't access `$form`. _what sort of string do you want to add to the form? how is this string related to the form?_ there could be a very easy alternate method. So if you answer these questions, maybe someone can help you out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create the form object at your controller and pass it to the view via the 2nd argument of the render() function..

```
// inside controller
$form = $this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
    'id'=>'report-form',
    'enableAjaxValidation'=>false,
    'enableClientValidation'=>true,
    'focus'=>array($exps[0],'productname'),
));

$this->render($myView, array(
    'form' => $form,
));
```